# Calculate the position of a Point B, so point B, with rotation point A, looks at a point C with always same distance to A

Tags: vectors, rotations

I have 3 points and one point's direction in 2D space.

Point A and point C are free moveable points.

Point B has always the same distance to point A and point B has a look direction and should always rotate around point A, so point B looks to point C.

I have always given point A's position and point C's position.
The problem is to find point B's position with the according rules above.

I illustrated the problem for more clarification:
[Point B's position update illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ5BV.png)

What would be the formula to get the proper position?

Comment: With vectors it's very easy. Just define a vector $CA$; and then $CB$ is some constant times $CA$. That's it for the math part, I think.

Comment: I doubt there is more than one solution if $AC<AB$, in that case can't be $B$ in other side of $C$ and it keeps the same look direction to $A$ and $C$ ? I mean if you take $S_{A}(B)$ instead of $B$ in the illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $d = |\overline{AB}|$
- $\vec{OA}$, $\vec{OC}$ the position vectors of points $A$ and $C$
- $\vec{CA} = \vec{OA} - \vec{OC}$

Then the position vector of $B$ is

$$\vec{OB} = \vec{OA} + \frac{d}{|\vec{CA}|}\vec{CA}$$

Comment: Here a quick proof, $B$ looks to $A$ then $C$ that means $\exists\alpha>1,\vec{BC}=\alpha\vec{BA}$ 
iff $\exists\alpha>0,\vec{AC}=\alpha\vec{BA}$ iff $A\ne C$ and $\vec{AB}=\frac d{CA}\vec{CA}$